# Vue.js uses old values of environment variables after I change them

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, environment-variables

I'm working on a Vue.js project. I have a `.env.development` file containing some `VUE_APP_*` environment variables. I changed the value of some variables but the Vue.js code still uses the previous values.

I tried everything: I stopped and relaunched the server with `npm run serve`, I deleted `node_sass` folder and launched `npm install` again, I completely reinstalled nodejs (I also deleted `~/.npm` folder), I cloned a fresh copy of my project from the repository, I rebooted my computer, but it still reads the old values of the variables.

I also tried to delete the `.env.development` file and it gave me an error, which means that it is reading the variables from the right place, but when I restored the deleted file it kept reading the old values.

If I change the value of a variable it still shows the old value, if I add a new variable it shows `undefined`. I do not have other environment files, I also searched the name of the variables in all file contents and that's the only place in which it's declared.

Do you know if Vue or Node.js are keeping cached variables somewhere?

I am using the latest version of Linux Mint with node.js 10.19.0, npm 6.14.4 (I also tried with the latest versions) and Vue.js 2.6

Thank you

EDIT: here's the code

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    created() {
      console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_MYVAR);
    },
    data() {
      return { }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Node should not cache a file's content. Can you include the part of your code that read the file ?

Comment: Ok, I added the code to the post

Comment: The code you have included is the code that uses the environment variables, not the one that reads the file.

Comment: What's the difference in practice? Anyway, what I mean is that when I `npm run serve` my Vue.js app the output of console.log is the old value

Comment: 1. Are you sure your mode is set to `development`? 2.Do you have any fallback values?

Comment: 1. in `package.json` I have `scripts: serve: "vue-cli-service serve"` which should be in dev mode by default, and when I run `npm run serve` it says `Note that the development build is not optimized.` so it should be in dev mode. 2. those values are declared only in that file (I searched the var name in all files by content to be sure)

Comment: @Taekwondavide The content of the `.env.development` file is not magicaly loaded in memory. There should be few lines of code somewhere (most likely in the entry file) that reads the file. If you are using a boilerplate, check the files for the file name, or "dotenv" (which is an NPM module often used for loading environment variables from files)

Comment: I cannot find anything that loads those variables. I though that `npm run serve` replaced environment variables while compiling. Anyway, if I delete that file it gives me an error because it cannot find that variable, so that I'm quite sure that it tries to read it from that file... The only problem is that the value is not the right one

Comment: @Taekwondavide take a look at the stacktrace of the error when the file is missing, you should be able to find where the loading process is written.

Comment: There is nothing helpful in browser's console. I only got a "failed authentication" error which is related to the wrong value, but that error is in a huge eval("2000 characters of JS code") expression, which contains the variable name, in a huge app.js file of half a millio characters, which is generated by npm, and it's quite impossible to debug

Comment: @Taekwondavide What I think can be wrong is that you might have 2 servers on. Are you sure you have killed all servers in all open terminals? If you are sure, what you can try is rename `.env.development` to just `.env`. Or delete  `.env.development` and create new `.env`. Then restart the server. Vue CLI should load the new file as default.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem and it was because the vue server was already running unknowingly to me so when I ran `vue-cli-service serve` it wasn't  updating  the env variables that appeared  in  my browser. To fix  this I found the process running on port 8080, the  default port  for vue and killed it. First  run `lsof i:8080` and kill the node processes using `kill {PID}`.